# VBA Using for...next calculate 1*2*3...*n

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner of VBA. My problem as title and I really don't know how to correct the code.Below is what I try but I think it's all wrong... Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Try_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

n = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(3, 2).Value

For i = 1 To n
i = i * (i + 1)

Next i

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(5, 2) = i


End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use the FACT formula?

Comment: And change those Integers to Long

Comment: If you really have to use a For i ... next i (sounds like this is for a class), why not store values in an array from 1 to n, then multiply the previous stored output value using array(i) from lower to upper bound?  Or similarly, use a second variable to store the output so you get k = k * i

Comment: As @pierre44 notes, you should not 'manually' adjust the counter used in a For ... Next loop.

Comment: btw, if need to increment by something other than 1 for each loop, you can adjust the optional Step parameter.

Comment: Guys guys guys, I feel like you're overcomplicating things a little here. While I absolutely agree that there are other superior ways of achieving what OP intends to do and there's nothing wrong with pointing it out, let's keep in mind he/she probably is very new to programming altogether and has no / very little idea of how to impelement an array to a for loop, how to apply a WorksheetFunction or even why should the Integers be changed to Long.

Comment: In this case you can set the value of cell B5 to the factorial of cell B3 directly by using `[B5]=[Fact(B3)]`

Comment: Thank you all. Yes,I'm very new. It's not for my class but for learning how to write for...next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change ***i*** in the loop:

```
Sub Try_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim prod As Long

    n = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(3, 2).Value
    prod = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        prod = prod * i
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(5, 2) = prod
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another variable to calculate it as below:

```
Sub Try_Click()



Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim k As Long
k = 1
n = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 2).Value

For i = 1 To n

k = k * (i)
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(5, 2) = k


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional variable for the result. Because if you change `i` within the `For` loop you fail the auto increment of the loop.

Also I recommend to use `Long` instead of `Integer` (for `result`). Why? Because for `n > 7` it will already exceed the limits of `Integer` and throw an overflow error. `Long` at least lasts until `n = 12`. For more you will need to use `Double` but that will result in an approximated result for `n > 18`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MultiplyN()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    n = 10 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(3, 2).Value

    Dim result As Long
    result = 1

    For i = 1 To n
        Debug.Print result & " *" & i & "=" 'look this output in the intermediate window
        result = result * i
    Next i 'auto increments i

    Debug.Print result
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(5, 2) = result
End Sub
```

Note that all `Debug.Print` lines are not needed to calculate but just to illustrate in the intermediate window what happens.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, I also would have done:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Try_Click()
    Dim n As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")
        n = .Cells(3, 2)
        .Cells(5, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(n)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @SJR suggestion in VBA if you don't want to use formula in cell B5:

`=FACT(B3)`

Code will be:

```
Sub Try_Click()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(5, 2)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=FACT(R[-2]C)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't even need that much overhead to do this calculation - it can be done with `[B5]=[Fact(B2)]` or `Sheet1.[B5]=[Fact(Sheet1!B3)]`, if necessary.